# 16:9 ration for pdf in mpdf

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am using mpdf for generating the mpdf document but I need it in the aspect ration of 16:9. The height is fine for my document but I need to increase the width of the document.

I tried various answers in Stackoverflow community but none of the answers helped me. Here's my code

```
$mpdf = new mPDF("en-GB-x","Letter-L","","",30,30,30,30,6,3);
```

I need to increase the width now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the size of your document as an array of width and height in milimeters. With landscape letter height 190mm, the width in 16:9 is calculated as 336mm.

mPDF 7.x

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'en-GB-x', 'format' => [336, 190]]);
```

mPDF 6.x

```
$mpdf = new mPDF("en-GB-x", [336, 190], "", "",30,30,30,30,6,3);
```